# Properties for collection_radio_buttons in simple_forms to wrap all in div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, wrapper, simple-form

I am creating radio buttons with simple_forms using collection_radio_buttons:

```
<div class="toggle-group">
  <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :question,
    [[true, 'Yes'] ,[false, 'No']], :first, :last,
    item_wrapper_tag: false, boolean_style: :inline %>
</div>
```

for getting this:

```
<div class="toggle-group">
  <input type="hidden" name="user[question]" value="">
  <input type="radio" value="true" name="user[question]" id="user_question_true">
  <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="user_option_true">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" value="false" name="user[option]" id="user_option_false">
  <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="user_option_false">No</label>
</div>
```

I've created some css which generates the input type 'hidden'.
What do I have to add in **collection_radio_buttons** to get the div wrapper with the class="toggle-group" instead of writing it by myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :question,
  [[true, 'Yes'] ,[false, 'No']], :first, :last,
  item_wrapper_tag: false, boolean_style: :inline, 
  collection_wrapper_tag: "div",
  collection_wrapper_class: "toggle-group" %>
```

Add `collection_wrapper_tag: "div",` to wrap the collection in a  tag. Add `collection_wrapper_class: "toggle-group"` to set the class to the div tag. Docs: [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/SimpleForm%2FFormBuilder%3Acollection_radio_buttons) and